# Is it possible to get eBay item description with requests and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: html, events, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to collect data from shoes on eBay. For every item I want to collect all data including the custom description to build up a database. I have collected all aspects such as price, shipping title etc. with requests and BS4. Unfortunately, the only thing missing is the custom item description.

This seems to be an event html, which in a browser is loaded automatically, but not with requests and BS4. I would prefer to do it with requests and BS4, as the script is almost ready, and scraping through for example Selenium is much slower. The example I am working on is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

source=requests.get("https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIGNED-2000-NIKE-AIR-JORDAN-1-HIGH-BANNED-1985-ROOKIE-RETRO-SHOES-AUTOGRAPH-UDA/392861887827?hash=item5b7864ad53:g:njcAAOSw9rpfALFX")
Nike_shoe = soup(source.text, "lxml")
```

The description part I am trying to filter contains, among other lines, the following excerpt:
[image: Excerpt of target HTML]
This can be found a bit lower on the eBay page. This description is part of the following HTML structure:

[image: Event_example]

When I scan through the Nike_shoe soup, this text is not present. I have tried to parse the source.text as lxml, html.parser, html5lib and xml.

I have also tried to use [Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) package which should have full JavaScript support:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
source = session.get('https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIGNED-2000-NIKE-AIR-JORDAN-1-HIGH-BANNED-1985-ROOKIE-RETRO-SHOES-AUTOGRAPH-UDA/392861887827?hash=item5b7864ad53:g:njcAAOSw9rpfALFX')
Nike_shoe=soup(source.text, "html5lib")
```

But unfortunately, I was still not able to retrieve this data. Also I am not familiar with this package, so perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Edit 22/08/2020 13:41:
Both answers below (@Andrej Kesely & @p1xel) give correct results. p1xel his answer can be implemented as follows:

```
source=requests.get("https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIGNED-2000-NIKE-AIR-JORDAN-1-HIGH-BANNED-1985-ROOKIE-RETRO-SHOES-AUTOGRAPH-UDA/392861887827?hash=item5b7864ad53:g:njcAAOSw9rpfALFX")
Nike_shoe = soup(source.text, "lxml")
iframe=requests.get(Nike_shoe.find(id="desc_ifr")["src"])
Custom_description = soup(iframe.text, "html5lib")
print(Custom_description.find("td").text
```

```
                            SIGNED 2000NIKE AIR JORDAN 1 HIGH BANNED 1985 ROOKIE RETRO SHOES AUTOGRAPH UDA SIGNED IN PRESENCE OF UPPER DECK REPRESENTATIVES•  SHOES ARE OFFICIAL RETRO FROM 2000, BRAND NEW WITH ORIGINAL BOX AND RETRO CARD Beautiful signature accompanied by  CERTIFICATE OF AUTHENTICITY FROM THE UPPER DECK COMPANY, which currently HOLDS AN EXCLUSIVE RIGHTS to ALL authorized authentic Jordan autographed memorabilia & trading cards (No 3rd party authentication here!)Have a peace of mind knowing that YOU ARE GETTING THE REAL DEAL RECENTLY ACQUIRED BIG COLLECTION FROM A PRIVATE COLLECTOR, PLEASE CHECK OUR AUCTION PERIODICALLY AS WE WILL CONTINUE TO POST NEW ITEMS DAILYIt says on the certificate that "Each individual product that bears the original autograph is signed in the presence of an Upper Deck Authenticated representative and registered by its numbered hologram and kept on permanent file", as part of UDA's patented 5-Step Hologram process. (NO LETTER OF OPINION HERE!) Pictures are from the actual shoe you are bidding on....  BUY FROM A REPUTABLE COLLECTOR, Please check my feedbacks from previous satisfied buyers and bid with confidence.BUYER TO PAY $100 FOR FULLY INSURED shipping with tracking number & signature confirmation. International buyer are responsible for any import/customs duty fee that might be charged upon delivery of the packageRECENTLY ACQUIRED BIG COLLECTION FROM A PRIVATE COLLECTOR, PLEASE CHECK OUR AUCTION PERIODICALLY AS WE WILL CONTINUE TO POST NEW ITEMS DAILYALL SALES ARE FINAL. MAKE SURE TO CHECK MY OTHER AUCTIONS FOR MORE GREAT MJ MEMORABILIA
```

As p1xel his answer is completed through the requests format on the same page, this will be chosen as the accepted solution, but both solutions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the description is within an iframe.

You need to find the `iframe` with id `desc_ifr` and simply make a request to its `src`.

This should do what you want (untested):

`requests.get(Nike_shoe.find(id="desc_ifr")["src"])`

Comment: I am unsure how to implement this solution. Where to put the target URL in this requests statement?

Comment: Replace `soup` with `Nike_shoe`, or whatever you call your BeautifulSoup instance. This already has the HTML of your original target URL. The extracted `src` is a URL which is passed to requests. I have edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this implies I have to perform two request statements to retrieve the desired text? I have implemented your answer in my question above.

Comment: Yes you need to perform two requests, but I assumed you would request the original page anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The description is loaded from different URL, you only need item Id, in this case number `392861887827`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIGNED-2000-NIKE-AIR-JORDAN-1-HIGH-BANNED-1985-ROOKIE-RETRO-SHOES-AUTOGRAPH-UDA/392861887827?hash=item5b7864ad53:g:njcAAOSw9rpfALFX'
item_descr_url = 'https://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?item={item_id}'

item_id = url.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1]  # this should be `392861887827`

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item_descr_url.format(item_id=item_id)).content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
eBay
SIGNED 2000NIKE AIR JORDAN 1 HIGH BANNED 1985 ROOKIE RETRO SHOES AUTOGRAPH UDA
SIGNED IN PRESENCE OF UPPER DECK REPRESENTATIVES
•  SHOES ARE OFFICIAL RETRO FROM 2000, BRAND NEW WITH ORIGINAL BOX AND RETRO CARD
Beautiful signature accompanied by  CERTIFICATE OF AUTHENTICITY FROM THE UPPER DECK COMPANY, which currently HOLDS AN EXCLUSIVE RIGHTS to ALL authorized authentic Jordan autographed memorabilia & trading cards (No 3rd party authentication here!)
Have a peace of mind knowing that YOU ARE GETTING THE REAL DEAL
RECENTLY ACQUIRED BIG COLLECTION FROM A PRIVATE COLLECTOR, PLEASE CHECK OUR AUCTION PERIODICALLY AS WE WILL CONTINUE TO POST NEW ITEMS DAILY
It says on the certificate that "Each individual product that bears the original autograph is signed in the presence of an Upper Deck Authenticated representative and registered by its numbered hologram and kept on permanent file", as part of UDA's patented 5-Step Hologram process. (NO LETTER OF OPINION HERE!)
Pictures are from the actual shoe you are bidding on....  BUY FROM A REPUTABLE COLLECTOR, Please check my feedbacks from previous satisfied buyers and bid with confidence.
BUYER TO PAY $100 FOR FULLY INSURED shipping with tracking number & signature confirmation. International buyer are responsible for any import/customs duty fee that might be charged upon delivery of the package
RECENTLY ACQUIRED BIG COLLECTION FROM A PRIVATE COLLECTOR, PLEASE CHECK OUR AUCTION PERIODICALLY AS WE WILL CONTINUE TO POST NEW ITEMS DAILY
ALL SALES ARE FINAL. MAKE SURE TO CHECK MY OTHER AUCTIONS FOR MORE GREAT MJ MEMORABILIA
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. How did you know the description is loaded from the item_descr_url you provided? If I follow the event it links to ir.ebaystatic.com which I think is a server bank of eBay..